# Why added text of EditText appears on next page of ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-edittext, android-viewpager

I have a `EditText`, a `ListView` and a `EditText` inside a ViewPager.
The `Button` adds the text of the `EditText` into the `ListView`.
So my problem is, when the User want to add text , the text will be added but not in the same page of the `ViewPager` but in the next page.

My code

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] Titel;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

   // int[] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    private static final Map<String, Integer> TITLE_IMAGES =
            new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    static {
        TITLE_IMAGES.put("Arme", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        TITLE_IMAGES.put("Bauch", R.drawable.ic_launcher2);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] Titel) {
        this.context = context;

        this. Titel = Titel;
       // this.images = images;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Titel.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitel;

        ImageView image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipeview, container,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        txtTitel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeviewtitle);


        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitel.setText(Titel[position]);


        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeViewimage);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView

        String title = Titel[position];
        Integer imageRes = TITLE_IMAGES.get(title);
        if (imageRes == null) { // not found in map
            image.setImageResource(0);
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(imageRes);
        }

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listViewswipeview);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextswipeView);

        Button btnswipeview = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonswipeview);

        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        listItems.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnswipeview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View View) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        "You clicked the button",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }
}
```

swipeview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Titel"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:id="@+id/swipeviewtitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeViewimage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextswipeView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonswipeview"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ListView
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/listViewswipeview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerswipeview"

            android:entries="@array/day"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your *swipeview.xml* file. Maybe the view where you are adding the text (the ListView i guess) is in the next page. Not the same page as your EditText.

Comment: I did, now you can see it in my post.

Comment: As i seen in your xml, you have 4 pages in your ViewPager. Each child of the main view (the main LinearLayout in your case) will represent a page. So from your XML file: for the *first page* you have TextView + ImagView, in the *second page* you have EditText+Button+EditText, in the *third page* you have the ListView and in your *fourth page* you have the Spinner. If you want some items to be shown in the same page just put them on the same child (same LinearLayout in your case)

Comment: No everything is shown correctly, just if I want to add a text, the text will be added in the `ListView` on the second page and not on the `ListView` on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a scoping problem. The way ViewPager works is that it loads and caches views that it gets from the adapter. It shows one of the Views it has cached. But the lists you are adding things to belongs to the adapter, not the view being shown.

So when the ViewPager asks for the the next view (it does this so it can smoothly scroll without having to load the next view at event time), it replaces the List in the adapter. But the listener writes to the last created list, which updates the next views list.

I'd suggest using FragmentPagerAdapter (or FragmentStatePagerAdapter if you have a lot of pages). That way the list and the data it displays are contained in the same fragment.

EDIT:
You could try something like this

Use FragmentPagerAdapter

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private HashMap<Integer, Fragment> currentViews;
    private String[] titles;
    private int[] resIds;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] titles, int[] resIds) {
        super(fm);
        currentViews = new HashMap<>();

        assert titles.length = resIds.length : Log.wtf("ViewPagerAdapter", "title and image arrays must be the same length."); //there's probably a better way to do this.
        this.titles = titles;
        this.redIds = resIds;
    }        
    ...
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (currentViews.containsKey(position))
                return currentViews.get(position);
        else {
            SwipeViewFragment fragment = SwipeViewFragment.newInstance(YourActivity.this, title[position], reIds[position]); //Context for the ArrayAdapter threw me for a second. this assumes you're using an activity. If this is in Fragment use "YourFragment.getContext()"
            currentView.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }
     }
     ...
     @Override
     public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
         super.onDestroyItem(container, position, object);
         if (currentViews.containsKey(position))
                 currentViews.remove(position);
     }
}
```

The Fragment

```
private static class SwipeViewFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    EditText textInput;
    Context mContext
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ...
    public SwipeViewFragment() { //required to be blank
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(Inflater inflater, ...) {
         View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipeview, container, false); 
         Bundle args = getArguments() //this is where you pass data to the fragment thats present at instance time
         String title = args.getString("title");
         int resId = args.getInt("image");

         TextView titleTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.swipeviewtitle);
         titleTextView.setText(title);

         textInput = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id....)
         ...
         Button addButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonSwipeView);
         addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     String text = textInput.getText().toString;
                     list.add(text);
                     adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
         });

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, R.layout.list_item, list);
         return root
    }

    public static SwipeViewFragment new instance(Context context, String title, int resId){
         SwipeViewFragment fragment = new SwipeViewFragment();
         mContext = context;
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt("image", resId); //do better than this, use String constants, I'm being lazy
         args.putString("title", title);
         fragment.setArguments(args)
         return fragment;
    }
    ...
    //included methods to manipulate data in the Fragment
    public void doSomethig(args...)
}
```

Then the Activity can do something like

```
public doSomething(args...) {
     SwipeViewFragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(pagerAdapter.currentItem());
     fragment.doSomething(args...);
}
```

The bottom line is each of the Views displayed by the ViewPager needs its own List. The basic View class doesn't have a place for this. So you need to create a custom view from a layout. Which is what a fragment is, pretty much.

EDIT 2: I probably got something in this wrong. but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Do you maybe now how to add just my adapter? Because I pass data from my activity to my swipeview fragment and I don't know how to pass the data to the adapter.

Comment: As in, you need the views displayed by the ViewPager to react to events in the activity? That's trickier, because the views are created and disposed of as they are needed. You can create all the Views you need when you create the adapter, but this is inefficient.

Comment: do you have some good websites where I can see how to make a FragmentStatePagerAdapter ?

Comment: Well, the obvious one's not bad... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but can you maybe edit it with my values ? I just tried it two hours but I'm just failing.

Answer (score 0):

As i remember instantiateItem is called twice for position 0 and 1 (part of precaching).

So on startup you have already 2 instances of listView, listItems, editText,...

Maybe try to check your references according to the position